# How to load values into an array list from a resource

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

The ultimate goal is to add additional fragments to the program without modifying the code.  I want to do this by changing the array-values of the resource files(not at run-time).  One resource-array has the spinner values, another has the fragment file names.  The order that they are listed in the resource file is how they correlate: So the first spinner array-String correlates to the first fragment TypedArray item and so on.

I wrote a simple class so that I can keep a correlation between my spinner values and the fragments that the spinner value represents.  This is the class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class SensorList {
    int index;
    String name;
    Fragment sensorFrag;
    SensorList(){
        name="";
        sensorFrag=null;
        index=0;
    }
}
```

I want to populate an instance of this class with values from resource TypedList.  That is where I am having problems.  This is my code of that so far.  The last line is clearly in error as it doesn't have an index for the 'add'.

```
public ArrayList<SensorList> sensorList = new ArrayList<SensorList>();
    Resources res = getResources();
    sensorList.(res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.sensor_frag_names));  //This line is a problem.
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is there a cast that I can apply.
If this isn't clear, let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Resources resources = getResources();
    TypedArray name= resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.sensor_frag_names);
    TypedArray sensorFrag= resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.sensor_frag_codes);
    TypedArray index= resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.sensor_frag_index);

    SensorList slist= new SensorList (name.getString(index), sensorFrag.getFragment(index), index.getInt(index));

    name.recycle();
    sensorFrag.recycle();
    index.recycle();
```